# MoviePy subtitles: Subtitles not showing up when file is written

Tags: python, python-3.x, moviepy

I'm working on some simple code which I hope to incorporate into my main project, but I've hit a roadblock. Although I believe my code should work fine, the subtitles are not being put into the project.

Full code sample:

```py
from moviepy.editor import *
from moviepy.video.tools.subtitles import SubtitlesClip
from moviepy.video.tools.subtitles import file_to_subtitles

filename = input("Filename: ")
subtitletype = lambda txt: TextClip(txt, font='Georgia-Regular', fontsize=24, color='white')
srt2sub = file_to_subtitles("nttd2.srt")
sub = SubtitlesClip(srt2sub, subtitletype)
myvideo = VideoFileClip(filename)
final = CompositeVideoClip([myvideo, sub.set_position(["center", "bottom"])])
final.write_videofile("subtest.mp4")
```

The .srt file is in the working directory, but when the video processes there's no text to be seen. It just shows a black screen where the srt file goes past the video length, and no actual subtitle.

Comment: Can you include screenshot of observed behavior? And also, nttd2.srt - can you show the excerpt of the file in the question?